# How can I clear my browser cache in Microsoft Edge programatically using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

I was using the below function to clear browser cache from the chrome extension :

```
function clearBrowsingData(callback, sinceTime) {

var dataSetToRemove = {
    "appcache": true,
    "cache": true
};

var removeOptions = {
    "since": 0
}
if (sinceTime) {
    removeOptions = {
        "since": sinceTime
    }
}


chrome.browsingData.remove(removeOptions, dataSetToRemove, function (data) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        // Something went wrong
        console.warn("Whoops.. " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        // TODO: Show error to the user
        return false;
    } else {
        callback(data);
    }
});
}
```

But I need to do the same for the edge extension and I am not able to do it because chrome.browsingData.remove has been bridged in Edge . Can someone help me with an alternative to do the same?

Comment: I would be a very sad panda if an extension cleared the browser cache whenever it wanted.

Comment: Yes I can understand but I need to embed this functionality

Comment: There's no alternative.

Comment: @wOxxOm There must be something like some code in JavaScript to delete the history which can also delete the cache.

Comment: This is not just JavaScript, it's the access to browser internal functionality. In Edge it's not implemented yet.